# Access-Control-Allow-Origin Error when in Safari but not in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, cors, xmlhttprequest

I have www-Folder with an index.html inside. I opened the index.html in Chrome. At the point where i perform a XMLHttpRequest, it works perfectly. But if i do the same in Safari, it fails with

```
origin null is not allowed by acces-control-allow-origin
```

I did some google searches but found nothing

Comment: Most likely you are opening the same document from different origins in the two browsers or have, as a browser user (not a website developer) disabled security in Chrome. There’s not enough information in the question to tell for sure.

Comment: Origin null is what you get when you open a local file instead of going through a webserver.